# How does the event-loop treat promise nesting and chaining differently

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, event-loop

The manner in which the event-loop treats promise nesting and chaining differently is confusing me. Please consider the two sudo-javascript snippets I have written below...

**Scenario 1 - nested promises**

```
new Promise(()=>{console.log("one")})

new Promise(()=>{new Promise(()=>{console.log("2.5")}))

new Promise(()=>{console.log("three")})
```

Output -
one
2.5
three

**Scenario 2 - chained promises**

```
new Promise(()=>{console.log("one")})

new Promise().then(()=>{console.log("2.5")})

new Promise(()=>{console.log("three")})
```

Output -
one
three
2.5

I know the above is correct and will happen. However based on much of the over-simplist online explanations of promises moving through the stack->heap/event-table->event queue->stack->repeat I'm getting very confused. How does scenario1-line2 manage to block the third line of code so its nested promise finishes. I thought:
1. the function sent to the new promise on scenario1-line2 would pass through the event-table to the event queue
2. then once the stack was empty the function runs, creating the promise I nested
3. By this stage the scenario1-line3 promise had already run due the outer promises being async.
Where is my misunderstanding?

Comment: The callbacks passed to `new Promise` are invoked immediately.

Comment: As @tkausl alludes to you aren't really doing anything asynchronous here other than one call to `then()`. To understand this, you should make an example with real-world promises that `resolve()` in something like a `setTimeout`

Comment: There is a syntax error for the 2ns example in the 1at scenario, and the 2nd example in the 2nd scenario will not work since `.then` will not work as the promise is neither resolved nor rejected.

Comment: @tkausl and Mark Meyer you are right. When I add a "then" to the nested promise, I start to see the behaviour I was expecting; the nesting does not block asynchronous flow. The "new Promise(executor)" is merely invoking its executor function immediately. Thank you for the education.